# How to count repeated elements in a list in R?

Tags: r, list

I have a list with multiple elements per "sub-list"([[1]], [[2]], etc). My problem: I am trying to count how many of the elements within a sub-list are the same as an adjacent element in the same sublist.

I have no problems as long as the list does not consist of sublist by using the following code:

```
Adjacent <- function(data)
{
    output <- vector()
    for(i in 1:(length(data)-1))
    {
        if(data[i]==data[i+1])
        {
            output[i] <-1
        }
        else
        {
            output[i] <-0
        }
    }
    return(output)
}
sum(Adjacent(example))
```

But lets say we have a list like:

```
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"         

[[2]]
[1] "A" "B"        

[[3]]
[1] "A" "A"

[[4]]
[1] "C" "B"

[[5]]
[1] "A" "D" 

[[6]]
[1] "D" "D" "A" "C"      

[[7]]
[1] "B" "A"

[[8]]
[1] "B"

[[9]]
[1] "B" "D"
```

I would expect the output to be "2", as the first "A" in [[3]] and the first "D" in [[6]] are adjacent to an element of the same value. For that I would just need to run the function above for every sub-list but I don't know how to do that. Could anyone help me here?

Comment: Not sure but maybe also: `length(Filter(anyDuplicated, lst1))`? This however does not deal with adjacency.

Comment: @NelsonGon I am also not sure,but probably OP is interested in duplicates only if they are adjacent. That can't be checked by `anyDuplicated`. For this particular example, it returns `2` as no other component of the list has repeated elements.

Comment: @yarnabrina True, check my answer below and let me know.

Comment: What would this 2 represent: **The number of duplicates in each sublist or the total length that fits this adjacency rule.**?

Comment: @NelsonGon 2 would be the total number of elements directly adjacent to an element of the same value, not simply duplicates. Thanks anyway, `anyDuplicated` might come in handy aswell!

Answer (score 2):

We loop through the `list` with `lapply`, apply `rle` to get the `lengths` of same adjacent elements

```
lapply(lst1, function(x) rle(x)$lengths)
```

To extract only the length that are greater than 1,

```
Filter(length, lapply(lst1, function(x) with(rle(x), lengths[lengths > 1])))
```

---

If we need the length to be the same

```
lapply(lst1, function(x) with(rle(x), rep(lengths, lengths)))
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- list(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), c("A", "B"), c("A", "A"), c("C", 
"B"), c("A", "D"), c("D", "D", "A", "C"), c("B", "A"), "B", c("B", 
"D"))
```

Comment: Thanks! The first line of code shows at least the position of the adjacent duplicates. But how could I extract the number to get just "2" as a result?

Answer (score 1):

A possibility that might be slow(Data from @akrun 's answer):

```
length(Filter(function(x) any(sapply(seq_along(x), function(y)
                                 x[y] == x[y+1])), lst1))
[1] 2
```

Comment: Cool. Personally I'd have done this: `length(x = Filter(f = function(t) any(rle(x = t)$length > 1), x = lst1))`. Not sure about the speed though.

Comment: Thanks, I however am not sure what OP would like to count exactly. The number of duplicates in each sublist or the total length that fits this adjacency rule.

Comment: Thank you very much NelsonGon and @yarnabrina, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility as mentioned in the comments to @NelsonGon's answer:

```
length(x = Filter(f = function(t) any(rle(x = t)$length > 1), x = lst1))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `rleid` function in `data.table` is great for this:

```
library(data.table)
sum(sapply(lst1, function(x) sum(table(rleid(x)) > 1L)))
# [1] 2
```

`rleid` increments every time the value of a vector changes, i.e. `rleid(x) = 1L + cumsum(x != shift(x, fill = x[1L]))`. So if an `rleid` value appears more than once, we can infer a value was repeated -- that's what `table() > 1L` does. Then we `sum()` this count within list element and `sum()` over the whole list.